# Can I ignore term frequency and it's affect on relevance in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is it possible to disable the affect that term frequency has on the relevance of your search results in Azure Search. Basically I want to achieve something similar to what Elastic Search allows (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scoring-theory.html#tf) Elastic search allows term frequency to be ignored on a field level by setting "index_options:docs" in your field definition.

Is it possible to do this in Azure Search?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the exact same thing here...

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to configure your index to ignore term frequencies when calculating relevance score.

Please create a post with this feature request on our User Voice page to help us prioritize: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

I'd love to understand the scenario you're trying to support and maybe recommend an alternative solution. Do you mind providing more details?

Comment: The use case for this I have is that I am using Azure Search for autocomplete/suggestions of locations.  An example is that I have two locations "Siem Reap" and "Siem Reap Royal Residences". If I do the query "siem AND re*" then Siem Reap Royal Residences is the first result because it has "re" in both "reap" and "residences".  Please note: I am using the normal search API and not Suggestions API since I don't have access to scoring profiles in suggestions.

Comment: If you're interested to try out an experimental feature that may be helpful here please reach out to me: janusz.lembicz at microsoft

Comment: @Yahnoosh Hi, what was the experimental feature mentioned? I'm also having this same issue and was wondering about a solution...